# Circumscribed triangle and tangent

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> In the given diagram , B C T are on circle and AT tangent to the circle at T , if AB =3 and BC=4 find $${AB +AT\over  AT+AC}$$

[image: ![image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR181.jpg)]

Comment: This remark has no effect on the answer to the question, but terminology matters. In the diagram I see an inscribed triangle. I see nothing I would call a circumscribed triangle.

Comment: My glitch David K, the key thing i saw that turns out to be ' power of a point' was similar triangles ATB & ATC ( along with THC ) gives side AT/ AB=AC/AT

Comment: That’s a good observation about the similar triangles. I would just call them “triangles” or “similar triangles” to avoid confusion, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the power of a point, then we have (with respect to point $A$ and a given circle): $$AT^2=AB\cdot AC = 3\cdot 7 =21$$
so $${AB+AT\over AC+AT}=...$$

Comment: YaY I actually derived that ! from similar triangles on the two triangles right ?

Answer (score 0):

Angles $ACT$ and $BTA$ both measure half the intercepted arc $TB$.  So the triangles vlcontaining these angles, both also containing angle $TCA$, are similar.  From the proportionality of corresponding sides of similar triangles, conclude that $|AT|$ is the geometric mean of $|AB|$ and $|AC|$.  Render $|AC|=7$ from betweenness and the rest is just substituting the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

My glitch David K, the key thing i saw that turns out to be ' power of a point' was similar triangles ATB & ATC ( along with THC ) gives side AT/ AB=AC/AT